# How likely is it to win a game of Barbarian Prince?

Tags: statistics, barbarian-prince

[Barbarian Prince](http://dwarfstar.brainiac.com/ds_barbarianprince.html) is a brutal paragraph based game. Your character must collect 500 gold and return to his homeland to win the game. Unfortunately, there are unfriendly guards, wolves, mobs of peasants, deadly ruins, and worse trying to end your life.

- **What are your approximate chances of winning a game within 70 days?**
- **What is the best strategy to use when attempting to win?**